# Pass parameters via ajax call in GET method using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, get

I have tried to retrieve data with particular item details. So i need to pass particular item id using ajax call in GET method. Please find below code i have tried,

**C#:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("matter")]
public List<MatterLookup> LookupValuesForMatter(ClientDetails data)
{

}

public class ClientDetails
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
var clientId = $("#client").val();
var data =
    {
        clientId: clientId,
    }
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "matter",
   data: data,
   success: function (response) {
               if (response != null) {
               }
   }
});
```

When i have try to pass parameters, received null instead of particular list id. Actually i have done with POST method already but i need to do using GET method.

Please suggest if you have any idea,

Thanks.

Comment: All your passing is a value for `clientId`, therefore you GET method should be `public List<MatterLookup> LookupValuesForMatter(string clientId)`

Comment: And with your existing parameter you would have needed the `[FromUri]` attribute

Comment: I am actually try for pass list of values using GET method not a single value.

Comment: What 'list'? You model certainly does not accept a `List<T>`. And what is the value of `clientId` in your view - is that from a `<select multiple>`? You need to explain the problem in your question.

Comment: I am not try to pass List<T>. Actually model will be have more than one variable. So i am asking question as simple code.

Comment: So how do you expect a correct answer :) - read my 2nd comment!

Comment: 2nd point working fine. Please put as answer i will mark as accepted answer. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, web-api binds complex objects from the body. Since you making a GET, and there is no body, you need to add the `[FromUri]` attribute so that the properties of your model are bound from the query string values.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("matter")]
public List<MatterLookup> LookupValuesForMatter([FromUri]ClientDetails data)
```

Alternatively, add a parameter for each name/value pair you are passing in the request

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("matter")]
public List<MatterLookup> LookupValuesForMatter(string clientId, .... ) // add simple type parameters as required
```

Comment: so for get if we add body it would via url as query string, correct?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Sorry, not sure I understood your comment. A GET has no body - the name/value pairs are sent in the query string (or route values), as opposed to posting a form, where the name/value pairs are sent in the body.

Comment: I meant was though we added body but it would go as query string for get ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, When you use `data: xxx` with `type: "Get"`, the values are translated to a query string - its not added to the body (but if its was a `type: "Post"`it would be added to the body of the request)